# WPF call method from MainWindow not working

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I have the following classes:

MainWindow:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MainMenu mainMenu = new MainMenu(this);
        menuFrame.Navigate(mainMenu);
        UserPage userP = new UserPage();
        contentFrame.Navigate(userP);
    }

    public void LoadAPage(Page page)
    {
        contentFrame.Navigate(page);
    }
}
```

MainMenu:

```
public partial class MainMenu : Window
{
    private Window switchPage;

    public MainMenu(MainWindow mainP)
    {
        Window mainWindow = mainP;
        InitializeComponent();
        switchPage = mainP;
    }

    private void btn_navigate_user(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserPage userP = new UserPage(ServiceLogic);

        //switchPage = Window.GetWindow(PageSwitcher);
        //switchPage.LoadAPage(new UserPage());
    }
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use the `LoadAPage`-method from the MainWindow. The MainMenu and UserPage are childs from the MainWindow. The problem is, no matter what I try, I cannot reach the `LoadAPage` method. I've tried setting the Owner but that doesn't work. When trying `mainMenu.Owner = this;`, Visual Studio says ``` Mainmenu does not contain a definition for 'Owner``. When I give the parent class as a  parameter to the child class, there are no errors but the method ```LoadAPage` is unknown there.

What am I doing wrong? How should I solve this?

EDIT: Changing MainMenu to a Window instead of UserControl makes me able to set the Owner. Still, I can't reach the method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What a mess :) Try this

```
private MainWindow switchPage;

public MainMenu(MainWindow mainP)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    switchPage = mainP;
}

private void btn_navigate_user(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserPage userP = new UserPage(ServiceLogic);
    switchPage.LoadAPage(userP);
}
```

However i think you ll be better off using events, instead of passing your window object to its childs.

Comment: Yeah, I've been racing against the clock to get this finished before over 10 minutes, started 4 hours ago. Changing it to `MainWindow` did the trick, now it's all working. It's not the nicest thing, but considering I have little experience and I have to show a demo in (now 4 minutes), I'm pretty happy the way it looks now! You saved me! <3